# Getting JSON data from ORACLE into Jquery Datatables

Tags: javascript, php, json, oracle

I am trying to put  JSON data into my datatables but somehow it doesn work. Please help me,

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('../vendor/process/process_vendor.php', function(response) {
        $('#vendorlist').DataTable({
          processing: true,
          data: response.data,
          columns: [
            { data: "PO_NO"}
          ]
        });
        window.someGlobalOrWhatever = response.balance;
      });
</script>
```

and this is the process_vendor.php

```
$sql = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT VPI.PO_NO FROM VW_PO_INFO@WENFINANCE_WENLOGINV_LINK VPI WHERE VPI.PROJECT_NO LIKE '%' AND VPI.PROJECT_NAME LIKE '%'");
$errExc = oci_execute($sql);

if (!$errExc){
    $e = oci_error($sql);
        print htmlentities($e['message']);
        print "\n<pre>\n";
        print htmlentities($e['sqltext']);
        printf("\n%".($e['offset']+1)."s", "^");
        print  "\n</pre>\n";
} else {

    $res = array();
    while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $res[] = $row;
    } 
    $listPO = json_encode($res, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    print_r($listPO);

    oci_free_statement($sql); // FREE THE STATEMENT
    oci_close($conn); // CLOSE CONNECTION, NEED TO REOPEN
}
```

and the JSON DATA:

```
[
  { "PO_NO": "0928-57\/WEN\/15" },
  { "PO_NO": "0928-57\/WEN\/15" },
  { "PO_NO": "0923-59\/WEN\/15" },
  { "PO_NO": "0916-57\/WEN\/15" },
  { "PO_NO": "1002-06\/WEN\/15" }
]
```

Comment: You need to parse your JSON..`var responseObj = JSON.parse(response)` and then `data:responseObj.data`

Comment: i did this '$.getJSON('../vendor/process/process_vendor.php', function(response) {
        var responseObj = JSON.parse(response);
        $('#vendorlist').DataTable({
          processing: true,
          data: responseObj.data,
          columns: [
            { data: "PO_NO"}
          ]
        });
        window.someGlobalOrWhatever = response.balance;
      });' But it doesnt work

Comment: you do not have key `data.`

Comment: @Konz Mama: Is it working or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you do not have key `data` in your response try using:do `console.log(response)` to check if you have received the data properly.

```
 var responseObj = JSON.parse(response);
```

then use `responseObj` for data.

```
data: responseObj,
```

Example from your raw data:

```js
var response=[ { "PO_NO": "0928-57/WEN/15" }, { "PO_NO": "0928-57/WEN/15" }, { "PO_NO": "0923-59/WEN/15" }, { "PO_NO": "0916-57/WEN/15" }, { "PO_NO": "1002-06/WEN/15" }];

$('#vendorlist').DataTable({
          processing: true,
          data: response,
          columns: [
            { data: "PO_NO"}
          ]
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<table id="vendorlist"></table>
```

Comment: this is my full code and still doesnt work

$.getJSON('../vendor/process/process_vendor.php', function(response) {
        $('#vendorlist').DataTable({
          processing: true,
          data: response,
          columns: [
            {data: "PO_NO"}
          ]
        });
        window.someGlobalOrWhatever = response.balance;
      });

Comment: $.getJSON('../vendor/process/process_vendor.php', function(response) { console.log(response); $('#vendorlist').DataTable({ processing: true, data: response, columns: [ {data: "PO_NO"} ] }); window.someGlobalOrWhatever = response.balance; });   try this and see what is shows in console.